# HTTP error 400 in AJAX POST request

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

I'm trying to make a very simple program that sends a variable to a server, to write out then.

According to Opera, it gets an HTTP 400 (Bad Request) at the end of `Display()`.

**.jade file**

```
button(type='button', onclick='Display()') Display data

#modify
    p Lorem ipsum Display

script
    include main.js
```

**main.js**

```
function Display(){

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var parameter = { "Name": "Katamori" };

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("modify").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
    };

    xhttp.open("POST", "displayer.js", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    xhttp.send(parameter);

};
```

**displayer.js**

```
function (req, res) {
    if (req.method == 'POST') {
        var jsonString = '';

        req.on('data', function (data) {
           jsonString += data;
        });

        req.on('end', function () {
            console.log(JSON.parse(jsonString));
        });

        req.on('error', function () {
            console.log("ERROR!");
        });
    }
}
```

I attempted to change `parameter` from JSON to simple text (with RequestHeader too), and in that case, I got an HTTP 404 error.

What's the reason and what's the proper solution?

Comment: have you tried to log `xhttp.responseText`?

Comment: An *algorithm* is a series of steps that solve an abstract problem (for example, searching in a string). It ususally exists as a textual description on paper. What you want to create is a program.

Comment: @The not yet; the only thing I could figure out is that it apparently has no value in case of HTTP error 400.

Comment: @Tomalak yep, sorry for that.

Comment: Another mistake in wording: `{ "Name": "Katamori" }` is **not** JSON. It's a JavaScript object literal (an object, for short). JSON is a text format, you would use a string to represent it in JavaScript. It's crucial to understand the difference, because that difference (*JavaScript objects are not JSON*) is what causes the error you see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't sending JSON, serialize your data to JSON and send it

```
xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(parameter));
```

Comment: It still throws back a 404, in the identical place.

Comment: Post your routing code, I'm guessing you have not set up a route named `displayer.js`

Comment: You're right, I didn't think it's necessary because `displayer` is not a site to visit, unlike the one that contains `main.js` - I guess I should fix it then.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can even send it in another way, like  below:

```
function display(){

  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var params = "name=Katamori";

  http.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("modify").innerHTML = http.responseText;
      }
  };

  http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  http.open("POST", "/", true);
  http.send(params);

}
```

server-side code

```
app.post("/", function(req, res){
  var jsonString = '';
  req.on('data', function (data) {
      jsonString += data;
  });

  req.on('end', function () {
      console.log(jsonString); // name=Katamori
  });
});
```

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)

It works for me.

Thanks, i hope it will help you

Comment: `Refused to set unsafe header "Content-length"` and also a 404 at the end of main.js - also, I guess you meant `xhttp` instead of `http`, or aren't you?

Comment: Oh, thanks! It looks much better, though it still throws back an error - `InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED.`

Comment: the error message is still identical. I copied without modification (as it wasn't necessary) and even checked it out, but have no idea. After reversing the order of `open` and `setRequestHeader`, another 404 error occurs.